# "[object Object]" instead of Object is passed to ng-model for <select> when I select an option with Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use an example from Angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
"Using ngValue to bind the model to an array of objects" section.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-ngvalue-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="ngvalueSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="ngvalueselect"> ngvalue select: </label>
    <select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" multiple>
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" ng-value="option.value">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <pre>model = {{data.model | json}}</pre><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngvalueSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     model: null,
     availableOptions: [
          {value: 'myString', name: 'string'},
          {value: 1, name: 'integer'},
          {value: true, name: 'boolean'},
          {value: null, name: 'null'},
          {value: {prop: 'value'}, name: 'object'},
          {value: ['a'], name: 'array'}
     ]
    };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/aHgqeK1pQHS5zfiIjyZv?p=preview

The problem: Every `<option>` represents object. I select an item and "[object Object]" is assigned to ng-model of `<select>` instead of object.

Angular recommends to use ng-options instead of repeater with options but I need to use some extra logic for every option like ng-style (different for every option).

The question is: how to make object be passed as Object instead of String in ng-model of `<select>` when user select an option from select.

Comment: It's actually pretty interesting, since the default plunker from Angular docs page does not work, but if you change script src to the one, used on docs page (https://docs.angularjs.org/angular.min.js), it works perfectly.

Comment: You're right. Looks like they use different angular version in docs comparing to what they publish for distribution.

Comment: It's quite interesting: the latest published angular `1.x` version is `v1.5.8` but for angular docs `v1.5.9-build.5079+sha.eeb9ef0` is used.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `ng-options`?

```
<select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in data.availableOptions" multiple></select>
```

Working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/zVzTI6sR6LywC9vcZRkn

Comment: Since use want to use this select for fonts list, I need to set ng-style with font-family for every option.

Comment: Not exactly. I need to use different ng-style for every option element. So in terms of colors, every line in the list is colored with different color.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your select should look something like this:

```
<select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in data.availableOptions" multiple>
```

So there should not be any individual option item

Answer (score -5):

$(this).find(":selected").data("value")

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label for="ngvalueselect"> ngvalue select: </label>
    <select size="6" name="ngvalueselect" ng-model="data.model" multiple>
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" data-option="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <pre>model = {{data.model | json}}</pre><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and if jquery use:

```
$(document).on("change","select",function(){
    var objectOrStringReturend = $(this).find(":selected").data("value");
});
```

Comment: The question is regarding an Angular problem - attaching an on change handler via jQuery (outside of a directive) isn't very "angular" which is likely why this answer is being down-voted. Angular and jQuery are very different beasts.